# Python Selenium sends actionchain as text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working with Selenium and I want to simulate the past action.
I am doing it like this
`ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()`

But somehow, instead of pressing control + v, it prints this code line into the text field on the website.

Before doing the ActionChain I am writing into the textbox with `send_keys`.
But this should affect the ActionChain.

Comment: Writing into the textbox with `send_keys` also can be actionChain.`ActionChains(driver).click(driver. find_element_by_xpath('xxxx')).send_keys(v_key).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('v').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()`

Comment: @ElapsedSoul so could it be that this action chain is worked with like ```send_keys``` ? 
If so, how can i avoid that?

Comment: You do `send_keys` as an actionChain then you can do two actions together in one actionChain.

Comment: The ```send_keys``` is called inside a loop, thats why i dont use action chain for that

Comment: This line is working fine, it pastes the text from the clipboard, so, before this line, copy the text you want to paste, then try.

Comment: You can add the action to the actionChain inside your loop ,after all action added. then call perform. `actions = ActionChains(driver)` ,`actions.send_keys(xxx)`,`actions.xxx(xxx)`. `actionChains` can be added by separated